# What is the actual date a file was created?

Tags: windows, ntfs

I have a file on my Windows 2008R2 server.  When I right-click and open "Properties":

Its Created date is 8/10/2013
Its Modified Date is 6/27/2011
Its Last Accessed Date is 8/17/2014

What is the date the file was actually created?  I think I can ignore the accessed date.  But the Modified date is earlier than the Create date.

Which is likely the real Created Date?

Comment: I've removed extensive commentary about whether this question is on-topic. I don't feel strongly about it, but it does feel like a _Super User_ question. I'd argue that general feedback about Stack Overflow guidelines (i.e. that would not change the decision made) are best in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The create date is when the file was copied/created on the server itself.

[Description of NTFS date and time stamps for files and folders](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299648)

> - If you copy a file from C:\fat16 to C:\fat16\sub, it keeps the same modified date and time but it changes the created date and time to the
>     current date and time.
> - If you move a file from C:\fat16 to C:\fat16sub, it keeps the same modified date and time and keeps the same created date and time.
> - If you copy a file from C:\fat16 to D:\NTFS, it keeps the same modified date and time but changes the created date and time to the
>     current date and time.
> - If you move a file from C:\fat16 to D:\NTFS, it keeps the same modified date and time and keeps the same created date and time.
> - If you copy a file from D:\NTFS to D:\NTFS\SUB, it keeps the same modified date and time but changes the created date and time to the
>     current date and time.
> - If you move a file from D:\NTFS to D:\NTFS\SUB, it keeps the same modified date and time and keeps the same created date and time.